# How to align Lightning-input field-level-help with label when label is more than one line long?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-design-system, lightninginput

I'm using a lightning-input. The label of the input is a bit too long and appears on two lines. When I add a field-level-help, instead of putting it on the second line where there is plenty of space, it adds it on a third line. I was wondering if there was any way of aligning it properly with the label instead ? Because right now, it looks really bad.

[image: Non Aligned helptext]

As asked in the comment I have added the HTML, which is fairly simple and aligned with what is defined in the documentation.

```html
<div class="input-fields-container">
    <lightning-input label={labels.newConnCapacityRequested} type="number" value={newConnCapacityRequested} field-level-help={labels.newConnCapacityRequestedHelpText} required>
    </lightning-input>
</div>
```

```css
.input-fields-container {
  width: 286px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: To get this straight, you want the text ***Complete this field*** to appear above the input box?

Comment: @EmmanuelMaina no, I want the little 'i' to appear on the second line. Not on its own on a third line.

Comment: could you please post your html piece of code you are using.

Comment: @ShagunSharma I have added my HTML to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution I found was to separate the label using the label as defined in the lightning design system.

Here is my code

```html
<label class="slds-form-element__label">
    <abbr class="slds-required" title="required">*</abbr>
    <span class="slds-m-right_x-small">{labels.newConnCapacityRequested}</span>
    <lightning-helptext content={labels.newConnCapacityRequestedHelpText}></lightning-helptext>
</label>
<lightning-input type="number" placeholder={labels.kwPlaceholder} value={newConnCapacityRequested} variant="label-hidden" required></lightning-input>
```

And here is the result with the old solution above, and the new one below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a link that might help.

lwc lightning-input field-level-help styling

Comment: @EmmanuelMaina, thank you this helped me find a solution